# How to update data in to database in faster way in .net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, datatable

I am taking 50000plus data from one table in `oracle` DB and storing in to a `datatable` in c# after doing some operations,then i am updating in to another table in oracle database.Here the question is how to update data in to table in oracle DB in faster and efficient way.I created TPL in c# tasks,but i missed a lot of updates.So i guess TPL is only for short tasks? is it correct.
I have following plans which would be better

```
1>Create a process and put updation logic in it and run
2>Split the datatable in to 5 datatables contains 10000 records each and run each datatable in separate TPL threads.If this is correct i dont know how to split datatable in 5 datatable(what i know is DataTable.Select (x => x).Take (10000).ToEnumerable() gives you the first 10000 DataRows and DataTable.Select (x => x).Skip(10000).Take (10000).ToEnumerable() for the next 10000.does that okey??)
```

,can anybody suggest me?

Comment: Without seeing your code it is hard to tell why the TPL approach is failing. TPL is not only about short tasks. And without knowing what kind of operations on the data we are talking about it is hard to give any answer for this question. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: @Peter Bons so you meant 50000 plus records are not a big deal for tasks? i am doing a normal updation of each columns in a row based on old data

Comment: It will still depend on your implementation. The amount of records is less important than how you are using TPL. There will be many ways to chunk the data in smaller parts and it will require some instrumentation to find the fastest way.

Comment: Can this "processing" be done in the database? Since you are asking for fast and efficient, the answer is to process the data where it is, rather than take it all out, then process it, then put it all back.